# convert image to .icns file AppleScript Obj-C

Tags: image, icons, applescript, converters, applescript-objc

how can I convert a .png image to a .icns using applescript? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you just use sips?

```
sips -s format icns test.png -o test.icns
```

It doesn't seem to support 1024 x 1024 images or create smaller versions though.